# Microsoft.Web.Services3.ResponseProcessingException

Tags: wse, wse3.0

I deployed a web service that used WSE 3.0 to a test server. I am getting the cryptic error below. Have any idea what this means and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Microsoft.Web.Services3.ResponseProcessingException: WSE910: An error happened during the processing of a response message, and you can find the error in the inner exception.  You can also find the response message in the Response property. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: 'wsse' is an undeclared namespace. Line 1, position 97.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg, Int32 lineNo, Int32 linePos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.LookupNamespace(NodeData node)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ElementNamespaceLookup()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
   at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Xml.XmlSkipDTDReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Web.Services3.SoapEnvelope.Load(Stream inStream)
   at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Xml.SoapEnvelopeReaderWrapper..ctor(SoapClientMessage message, String messageContentType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Web.Services3.Xml.SoapEnvelopeReaderWrapper..ctor(SoapClientMessage message, String messageContentType)
   at Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol.GetReaderForMessage(SoapClientMessage message, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Since the dll was working when I called it from a windows client but was failing when called from a web service I suspected that the problem might be permissions related. I set the web service to impersonate a user with sufficient permissions. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158 for how to information. Now it works. Hope this helps someone else, Dan

Answer (score 0):

System.Xml.XmlException: 'wsse' is an undeclared namespace. Line 1, position 97.

Well if this statement is true then you have the wrong namespace. Check out your solution files to make sure they're under the write ns'es.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately that does not seem to be the real problem. The error is coming from a .dll that I built. I can call it from a windows client and I get the expected results. However, when I try to call the .dll from a web service I get the error. I suspect that there is some kind of firewall issue when it is called from the web service.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and it was a problem of date time synchronization between the server and the client. After setting the same time in the client and server, the error was fixed.